# Commutators for quantum Lie algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra

Can the usual definition of a Lie algebra via commutators be simply adapted
to quantum Lie algebras? Graphically you have the IHX scheme, with the X
being a virtual crossing (so to say). Does it suffice to replace it with a real
(knot-like) crossing and adapt the structure constants and coefficients
before IHX a bit?
EDIT: $[x,y]_q=xy-q*yx$ and replacing all brackets by this q-bracket is
a valid definition, but it does *not* answer my question, since in tensor
form, yx is xy times a virtual crossing, so to say, and virtual and real
crossings don't mix very well. I do have a conjecture for the formula,
though. It is probably correct at q=1 (I guess it's eq. 4.36 of "Birdtracks",
modulo a funny weight factor which is due to my choice of gauge, or that
I use undirected graphs), and this graphic should make it clear (the blue J
is the adjoint irrep, everything else can be any irrep):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP9Cj.jpg
The formula I'm seeking would then follow by applying it to a trivalent node
made from two defining and one adjoint irrep. I will subsequently verify
(or falsify :-) it by applying it to some simple examples like SU2(q) but
that doesn't replace a proof...

Comment: Based on the use of the terms "crossing" and "virtual crossing" this appears to be a question about knot invariants. Certainly, it makes no sense as a question about "representation theory" (of what?), or even about Lie algebras in the traditional algebraic realm.

Answer (score 1):

[Third Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9dwO.jpg) - Black: Any irrep - Blue: The adjoint irrep

This looks like the correct linear combination which at least
partially answers my problem:
a) In the classic limit, the P term crosscancels (as long as
lim P isn't infinite), and if lim Q=1/2 the IHX equation results. (It remains to express the unknown scalars P and Q as 6j salad.)
b) In the cubic skein case (E7 series), if the black line is the defining irrep, the lower pics sketch how to eliminate the adjoint. The result is identical to Przytyckis 6-tangle equation for cubic skeins, for a certain choice of P and Q.
The obvious generalization is asked in my [next question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248548/commutators-for-quantum-lie-algebras-revisited?noredirect=1&lq=1). :-)